# Any good presentation examples on why minimal + responsive design is a good approach for a website redesign?

Tags: responsive-design, flat-design, minimalist

I am making a presentation on responsive design and minimal design. Would be catered towards more elderly or less technical coworkers and stakeholders that do not yet know about this type of design and/or do not understand it.

Any real world examples or insight would be great.

Comment: +1 for having an awesome avatar. What was the question again?

Comment: Find a good responsive website and one that is build for desktop only and show them both on a tablet or smartphone. Also show some statistics on mobile browser usage and you should have a good case.

Comment: There is a gallery of websites that use media queries here http://mediaqueri.es/

Comment: I'd like to believe that simple math would convince people. Show how the numbers of people connecting to the internet on mobile devices is growing year after year--not to mention the number of people *only* accessing the internet on mobile devices. Combine that with the fact that building one responsive web site is cheaper than separate sites for each device. Granted, I've worked for several companies that can't grok that simple math, so YMMV.

Comment: Asking for examples of X isn't really what this site is for. Can you amend the question so that you're asking for a specific solution to a problem rather than for examples of things?

Comment: More people found it useful than not, how did i not state the problem? I asked for a specific solution to a problem I was having with not knowing the best way to translate what I know into easier terms. But thanks for moderating my question that people already found useful.